# Alternatives to Newtonsoft.JSON for Monodroid

Tags: json, xamarin.android

We currently use Newtonsoft.JSON for notation and serialization/de-serialization of JSON objects in our C# based projects (along the lines of the following), which we also need to share with an application which has been written using Xamarin MonoDroid

```
[JsonProperty("type")]
public string theType { get; set; }

....

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OurModel>>(jsonString);
```

However, the Newtonsoft.JSON isn't compatible with Mono

Presumably, there is an easy solution to handling JSON data BOTH within the C# environment as well as Monodroid? Ideally, so that we can have a common class that is shared between the two projects?

Comment: Have you looked into JSON.NET?

Comment: Do you have a link to some usage? When I searched Google for that, it took me over to the Newtonsoft.JSON page, which is what we're currently using.

Comment: @SeanAnderson How did you get on with this? Were you able to get it running on Android?

Comment: It would seem that we had some other code issues going on, and in fact, as you suggested, the version we are using (which is also, 7.0.1) does do the job. Thank you for the pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed on the Json.NET homepage, "Json.NET supports Windows, Windows Store, Windows Phone, Mono, and **Xamarin**."

Newtonsoft is the company that makes Json.NET - so the namespace that the library uses is "Newtonsoft.Json". They are both referring to the same library.

I have successfully used Json.NET in my Xamarin.Android applications.

If you aren't sure where to get a copy of the library that will work with your Xamarin.Android application, try using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Comment: Do you know what version you're using?

Comment: @SeanAnderson I am using version 7.0.1